# How to auto update days difference column daily?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am managing a database table which has many columns, two of them are following:

1. Last_Email_Send_Date (Datetime)
2. Days_Since_Last_Email_Send (int)

In second column, date difference of column 1 to current date is saved. Issue is, I have to update column 2 daily by a SQL job because days difference get changed daily. Is there any other technique so that days difference automatically get updated without running the job?

I have tried to create Computed Column but it not allowing to use non-deterministic function (getdate()).

I know it is not a good approach to save date value as well as days difference. Actually in my case table is using in a third party tool and I need to have both these columns.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create PERSISTED computed column with `GETDATE()`. You can create normal computed column, which is calculated at query execution time.

[Computed Column on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure)

```sql
create table #test(Last_Email_Send_Date date)

alter table #test add Days_Since_Last_Email_Send as (datediff(day,Last_Email_Send_Date,getdate()))

insert into #TEST values('2020-01-01')

select * from #test
```

```
+----------------------+----------------------------+
| Last_Email_Send_Date | Days_Since_Last_Email_Send |
+----------------------+----------------------------+
| 2020-01-01           |                        190 |
+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Venkataraman. How can we apply index on this column?

Comment: @Test123Site, you cannot apply index on this column, as it is not persisted. I would suggest you to `Index Last_Email_Send_Date` and arrive at a date, based on `Days_Since_Last_Email_Send` and use the date against `Last_Email_Send_Date`